# Гипотетическое "Помилев"

Tags: словообразование

Можно из слова "милый" образовать "помилеть" и "помилев"? Значение: стать милым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помилеть - есть такое слово. Электронные словари отсылают к Далю:
"Помилеть, стать кому милее прежнего, угодить в любовь, в милость. По дочери зять помилеет, по снохе сын опостылеет. | Стать миловиднее, милее, краше по наружности. Была себе сморчок, а выросла - помилела".

Вы хотите деепричастие "помилев"? Это будет авторская вольность в старорусском стиле. Надеюсь, вы создаете произведение художественной литературы. В каких-то иных текстах такое слово будет нелепым.

Comment: Да, всё так. Деепричастие совершенного вида для художественной литературы. Спасибо.